# Oozie keep adding a old version of httpcore jar to classpath

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

I'm keep getting an exception because Oozie add a wrong version of httpcore jar to classpath. I tryed different options such as

```
oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence
oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first
```

oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence does not respond at all and when I use oozie.launcher.mapreduce.user.classpath.first, application cannot load even one class.

In class path I can see two versions of http-core.

```
httpcore-4.4.1.jar
httpcore-4.2.4.jar
```

When application runs in stand alone mode, I'm not getting that exception.

Exception:

```
    Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain], main() threw exception, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:59)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.createConnectionSocketFactoryRegistry(ExchangeServiceBase.java:244)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.initializeHttpClient(ExchangeServiceBase.java:198)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.<init>(ExchangeServiceBase.java:174)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeServiceBase.<init>(ExchangeServiceBase.java:179)
    at microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService.<init>(ExchangeService.java:3729)
    at com.sonasoft.sonacloud.email.dispatcher.conn.EwsConnection.getConnection(EwsConnection.java:16)
    at com.sonasoft.sonacloud.email.dispatcher.conn.EwsConnection.getConnection(EwsConnection.java:10)
    at com.sonasoft.sonacloud.email.dispatcher.utils.EwsOperations.<init>(EwsOperations.java:47)
    at com.sonasoft.sonacloud.email.dispatcher.utils.EwsOperations.getInstance(EwsOperations.java:53)
    at com.sonasoft.sonacloud.email.dispatcher.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:56)
    ... 15 more
```

Oozie client build version: 4.2.0.2.3.2.0-2950

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you let us know what the source of each of the two `httpcore` JAR files is?

Comment: Hi Tim,
httpcore-4.2.4.jar from hdfs://ip:port//user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151027124452/oozie/

and httpcore-4.4.1 jar from the lib directory of the application I built.

Comment: Let's assume you can't change the classloader for Hadoop.  Then how did you build your app?  Can you use something like Maven, which would allow you to include the `httpcore` JAR at build time, but exclude it from runtime?

Comment: Yes, I used maven to build the application. Then put it in hdfs. And then I run the oozie command to execute the application

Comment: Show us the portion of the POM which has `httpcore`.  Use the `provided` scope for `httpcore`, which means that Maven will build with your version, but will exclude it at runtime, relying on the Hadoop framework for a JAR.

Comment: I did not use provided tag in pom. I'll use it and try it as you instructed. 

This is how the pom looks currently

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 3):

We have had this nasty issue with HortonWorks distro 2.3.2 *(shame on them)*:

- the Oozie "launcher" job always gets `httpcore` and `httpclient` in
  the CLASSPATH as part of the Hadoop client
- the Oozie "launcher" job always gets `httpcore` and `httpclient`
  as bundled in the "Oozie" ShareLib
- the Hive/Hive2 Sharelibs contain `httpcore` and `httpclient` in a
  **more recent version**
- from Hadoop point of view, `user.classpath.first` applies to **both**
  ShareLibs so it's a 50/50 chance of getting the right order for each
  JAR (so a 25/75 chance overall)

Bottom line: we had to

1. **remove** `httpcore` and `httpclient` from the "Oozie" ShareLib HDFS
   dir (duh!)
2. raise `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first` flag for all actions relying on Hive JARS *(i.e. Hive action, Hive2 action, Shell action calling the JDBC driver somehow, etc.)*

*Post-scriptum* -- the Oozie server keeps in memory a list of the JARs in each ShareLib, so that removing a JAR while the server is running will trigger errors in new jobs. If you don't want to stop the Oozie server, then the "proper way" to update a live ShareLib is to *(a)* create a new version in a new, time-stamped directory *[check the documentation...]* and *(b)* tell the server to resync on the newer libs with `oozie admin -sharelibupdate`

Comment: I removed the httpcore jar from hdfs. And then it complains saying " File does not exist: hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151027124452/oozie/httpcore-4.2.4.jar"

Comment: And then I executed this command. oozie admin -sharelibupdate
So now the error is gone!

Comment: I edited the answer. Accept it so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build with your local version of the `httpcore` JAR, but you don't want it present in your classpath, because Hadoop will provide its own version.  Then you should be using the `provided` scope for the `httpcore` JAR:

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>           <!-- this line is important -->
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

From the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) for `provided`:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I can still see two http-core jar files are in classpath. What I actually need is I need to keep the version 4.4.1.jar which is provided by me and ignore the jar file provided by oozie. Is that possible with "provided" tag

Comment: Is the `httpcore` JAR present in the build output from Maven?  It should not be.  And if it's showing up later on, then it means the framework is bringing in 2 JARs.

Comment: I'm using following in my pom file. 

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

That adds the http-core-4.4.1 to the lib folder when build using maven

Comment: So there are actually _two_ places in your project build which are using `httpcore`?  In any case, you can't around this one by using `provided` because presumably you need it when you run, thereby including its dependencies (`httpcore`) as well.

Comment: Here is my pom file.

http://pastebin.com/sUs4rv5y

I have removed the http-core dependency and still it build successfully but the http-core-4.4.1.jar is in lib folder.

Comment: http-core-4.4.1.jar is added by the aws-java-api dependancy.

Comment: Which `http-core` version was removed from your POM?

Comment: Have a look at how to [exclude dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) in Maven.  You might be able to find a way to exclude `http-core` from `aws-java-api`.  However, my feeling is that it might be easier to change the framework JARs.

Comment: My problem is actually not with maven. I need the jar file added by maven to run the program. But the problem is Oozie add another version of the same jar to the class path. When I run the program without using oozie all are fine :)

Comment: You are not following me.  If you can prevent Maven from including `http-core` from `ews-java-api` in your build, then your program should run.  In other words, my strategy is to let Oozie's added version of `http-core` be the only one present at runtime.

Comment: Got it. I'll try to find a way to exclude htttp-core from aws-api :) Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I found a way to exclude the jar using <exclusion> tag. Build successfully. Then there is only one jar in the classpath. That's the old version of the http-core jar. But I get another exception saying class not found. So I think the latest http-core jar is required to run the ews-java api

Comment: Then your only remaining option is to exclude Oozie's version of the `http-core` JAR at runtime.  Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of Oozie (other than it's a type of gun), so I cannot help you any further.  I will leave this answer up so that another guru might help you in a few hours.

Comment: One last thought: How do you specify dependencies for Oozie?  Can we somehow exclude the `http-core` JAR from there?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Oozie is a job scheduler. When I submits the built project to oozie it accepts it and submit the job to hadoop. I don't see a way to exclude dependencies from Oozie. So this question needs an answer for that.

Comment: There must be a way to do this, or else no one would use Oozie (other than to shoot people).