# Oozie loading jars provided by user first

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I have tried **oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first property** in workflow.xml to load my jars first over sharelib jars.
Unable to run workflow when this property is used. 
hadoop-hdfs is available in the provided jar and version is not incompatible

Comment: Well, what versions are you using and what is installed? AFAIK, the sharelib doesn't interfete with mapreduce classes anyway

Comment: That property won't work -- from YARN perspective, the sharelib JARs **are** "user-provided" JARs. You have to create a different version of the sharelib, with the newer JARs, and invoke that specific version in your workflow.

Comment: @cricket_007 To be more specific my problem is similar to the one in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869346/oozie-keep-adding-a-old-version-of-httpcore-jar-to-classpath

Comment: Are you using the same version of Oozie as that answer? Are you using Oozie as part of HDP or CDH or EMR?

Comment: I am using oozie as part of CDH and Oozie client build version: 4.1.0-cdh5.16.1, Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.16.1

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I have tried providing custom lib paths with property oozie.use.system.libpath  Even in this scenario I could see oozie share libs are getting loaded first.

Comment: That is exactly my point. _Your_ JARs and _sharelib_ JARs are loaded together and in random order. So I repeat: you have to build a custom sharelib, replacing the older JARs with newer versions.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your response. unfortunately I should not modify sharelib. I am trying with maven relocation strategy, but there are some unpredictable errors even with maven relocation. I will post updates soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maven relocation strategy can be used to avoid conflicting classes
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html
Posting pom.xml shaded plugin config which worked for me

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shaded.org.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```